# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime' and AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'concat'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

DATA SET HERE https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r24rrKWcIpA1x34tPY8olJFMtjzl0IRn

I am trying to convert my time series into type DateTime, so to do that I needed to make all the number eg.(1256,430,7) into same size eg.(1256,0430,0007) for  the to_datetime() to work.

So fist I separated the Entity according to their length and added number of zero required, concat the "Series" into one that were seperated.

*FIRST ERROR*

This error was sorted by using append() in Series. Then I tried to_datetime()

*Second Error*

I cant figure out what am I doing wrong

I updated my pandas library up to date.
Still the problem remains.
I tried this on Google Colab thinking might be some problem in my pandas lib.

```
a='0'+arr_time[arr_time.astype(str).str.len()==3].astype(int).astype(str)
b='0'+dep_time[dep_time.astype(str).str.len()==3].astype(int).astype(str)
c='00'+arr_time[arr_time.astype(str).str.len()==2].astype(int).astype(str)
d='00'+dep_time[dep_time.astype(str).str.len()==2].astype(int).astype(str) 
e='000'+arr_time[arr_time.astype(str).str.len()==1].astype(int).astype(str)
f='000'+dep_time[dep_time.astype(str).str.len()==1].astype(int).astype(str)
g=arr_time[arr_time.astype(str).str.len()==4].astype(int).astype(str)
h=dep_time[dep_time.astype(str).str.len()==4].astype(int).astype(str)

arr_time=pd.concat([a,c,e,g])
dep_time=pd.concat([b,d,f,h])

'''concat() is then replaced by append() ERROR detail is below

{AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-20-61e7a2e98b70> in <module>()
----> 1 arr_time=pd.concat([aa,ba,ca,pa])
      2 dep_time=pd.concat([ad,bd,cd,pa])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
__getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if 
self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'concat'}'''

arr_time=a.append(c).append(e).append(g)
dep_time=b.append(d).append(f).append(h)
datetime=arr_time.to_datetime(format="%H%M")

'''second error  BOTH OF THEM LOOK ALIKE

{AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5a63dad5c284> in <module>
----> 1 datetime=arr_time.to_datetime(format="%H%M")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if 
self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'}'''
```

Comment: - to convert a column to date time, you need the Month, Year and Day values, or the numerical representation of a datetime object. Do you have either of these? What does the (1256,430,7) represent?

Comment: 1256 represents 12:56pm

Comment: 7 represent 00:07am

Comment: Given data are not dates they represent time